# Good ways to store brownies?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, brownies

A friend is planning her wedding and wants to do a lot of brownies, rather than cake, for dessert. She's planning on making it herself, with the help of friends, but would like to make it at least a few days, if not a week or more, in advance. What would be a good way to store a lot of brownies? How long will they last?

Freezing is non-ideal, as freezer space is often tight at all of our homes and dealing with thawing/reheating lots of brownies evenly on the day may be problematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We store them at room temperature. If only for 3-4 few days: under plastic wrap or in the microwave. If about a week: in sealed Tupperware to keep the humidity from getting to them. I don't know if the humidity is an issue for everyone or only for those of us in a very humid climate. The refrigerator will make them last even longer but they won't taste as fresh after refrigeration. Freezer: 4-6 months.

The absolute best place I've found to store brownies though is in my stomach.

Comment: Personally, I think brownies taste *better* after sitting around for a few days...

Comment: @Knives: I'm not sure if I personally feel that way, but you're not alone. I've heard many other people say that too.