# Will freezing homemade brownies affect the texture and taste?

Tags: baking, flavor, freezing, texture

I have recently frozen two cakes and then served to positive feedback.

I'm wondering if the same would be true for chocolate brownies, as well as blondies.

I'm considering making them tomorrow (Tuesday) then thawing in time for a fair on Saturday.

My time is limited throughout the week and I'd like to cook some on Tuesday if possible.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/good-ways-to-store-brownies)? It sounds like you're just keeping them around for ~4 days; likely doesn't even need freezing

Comment: That's very good, thanks.  That answers my question.